# making an extended logical swap partition in manjaro

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot, manjaro, swap

my laptop is old and it uses MBR partitioning. therefore I can't have more than 4 primary partitions. I'm dual booting Manjaro and Windows 8.1. Windows is using 2 primary partitions and Manjaro also uses one for installation and another for swap. the problem is I want to have another partition to save my personal data. I want to know how can I delete the swap partition and make an extended partition that has one logical swap partition for Linux and another logical partition for my personal data? (I prefer windows to do the partitioning, I'm new to the Linux world)

thanks in advance.

Comment: If Windows is to do the partitioning, this question probably belongs to https://superuser.com/ . Also there's no guarantee that changing partitions won't affect Windows somehow

Comment: Is it possible to have an extended and logical partition for the swap on manjaro?

Comment: Do not use Windows to create Linux partitions. Use gparted from live installer. Do not know Manjaro specifically but 3 primary partitions, one extended partition containing any number of logical partitions is standard with all Linux & MBR partitions.

Comment: Manjaro's live installer won't let me create a logical swap partition. only primary is allowed. maybe I have to insert my HDD into CD Reader. hope I'll find a way to remove Windows. but PhotoShop is preventing me.